# How to plot two lists in descending order based on y values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists. The first is a list of strings `a`

```
['Agriculture/Forestry/Fisheries/Veterinary Medicine',
 'Architectural and Town Planning',
 'Business Administration and Related', ...]
```

and the second a list of floats `b`

```
[66667.0,
22283.0,
670091.5, ...]
```

When I use the following code to plot it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

a = ['Agriculture/Forestry/Fisheries/Veterinary Medicine',
'Architectural and Town Planning',
'Business Administration and Related', ...]
b = [66667.0,
22283.0,
670091.5, ...]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(a,b)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

the bars are arranged in alphabetical order according to the strings in list `a`.
How would I plot it so that the bars are arranged in descending order with respect to list `b` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple data rearrangement approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [
    'Agriculture/Forestry/Fisheries/Veterinary Medicine',
    'Architectural and Town Planning',
    'Business Administration and Related'
]

b = [66667.0, 22283.0, 670091.5]

b, a = zip(*sorted(zip(b, a), reverse=True))  # reverse sort data on 'b'

c = range(len(b))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(c, b)
plt.xticks(c, a, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

categories = ['Agriculture/Forestry/Fisheries/Veterinary Medicine',
 'Architectural and Town Planning',
 'Business Administration and Related']

values = [66667.0,22283.0,670091.5]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category', 'value'])
df = df.append([{"category":a, "value":b} for a, b in zip(categories, values)])

df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)[['category','value']].plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

- `list(zip(list_name, list_count))` zips the two lists into a list of tuples

  - Convert the list of tuples into a [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with `dtypes`
- [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) sorts by ascending (smallest to largest)
- `[::-1]` reverses the array
- The benefits are, `matplotlib` easily accepts arrays, and the `numpy` column can be passed with its name.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = ['Agriculture/Forestry/Fisheries/Veterinary Medicine', 'Architectural and Town Planning', 'Business Administration and Related']

values = [66667.0, 22283.0, 670091.5]

# get the length of the longest string in text, for the numpy str dtype
# this is only necessary if make sure the entire string is included in the array
str_len = max([len(t) for t in text])

# create numpy array with dtypes
t = np.array(list(zip(text, values)), dtype = [('text', f'S{str_len}'), ('values', int)])

# sort array
t = np.sort(t, order=['values'])[::-1]

# plot
plt.bar(x=t['text'], height=t['values'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]