# How to plot list of lists against list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

```
x = [2000,2001,2002,2003]
y = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    plt.plot(x,[pt[i] for pt in y])
plt.show()
```

I'm getting a `ValueError` of `4, 3`. I know that `x` and `y` must be equal. I thought `len(y[0])` would work.

For each of the sublists in `y`, I want to generate a line with their `x` values corresponding to `2000, 2001, 2002, 2003`.

Comment: Here is an associated question [How to plot two lists in descending order based on y values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483511/how-to-plot-two-lists-in-descending-order-based-on-y-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple Pythonic solution, do the following:

```
for y_values in y:
    plt.plot(x, y_values)

plt.xticks(x)  # add this or the plot api will add extra ticks
plt.show()
```

[image]

Each item in your `y` nested list is the list you want to plot against `x`, so this approach works perfectly here.

Comment: This solution is perfect. But I thought it was nice to work with a `pandas` approach on this, hence I added another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [2000,2001,2002,2003]
y = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(y).transpose()
df.index=x
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

And the result would be:

[image]
With output `DataFrame` as:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
      0  1   2
2000  1  5   9
2001  2  6  10
2002  3  7  11
2003  4  8  12
```

Comment: Neat approach. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

`[pt[i] for pt in y]` on `i = 0` will give you `[1,5,9]`.

I think you need `[1,2,3,4]`, so use `y[i]` instead of `[pt[i] for pt in y]`.